# Issue while installing naoqi with ROS

Tags: ros, ubuntu-20.04, nao-robot

I am new to ROS, I am trying to install naoqi for ROS noetic in ubuntu 20.04LTS,i have been following the steps given in the link : http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Tutorials/Installation

While checking the naoqi installation and running the give code line ($ ~/naoqi/naoqi-sdk-2.1.4.13-linux64/naoqi), i got stuck at this

[error-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCRUn.png)

So I tried to search for the problem in online, but i am not able to get it, the only thing i found is that the packages were deprecated, and i dont know how to solve that while installing naoqi,can someone please help me in solving this
Thank you.

Comment: Did you follow all of those tutorial steps exactly? Looks like the docs are written for older versions of ROS and all versions before Noetic target Python2.7

Comment: I did follow them exactly, i will try to do the same with older versions, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list changed sources according to your region?

Ever tried *$sudo apt-get update*? If there is any error, please change the source file '*source.list*' first.

Comment: Thank you for your response, there is no error when i tried the command $sudo apt-get update

Comment: You can try use *$python --version* to make sure python version is what u need.  I have tried the URL : http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Tutorials/Installation in Ubuntu20.04, but I'm sorry that I don't have the same problem as you, please reinstall ROS or Naoqi.

Comment: okay sure, i will check it once, may i know which version of Naoqi and ROS did you use?

Comment: Thank you @RxLucifer , when i tried to install the updated package i got the error, but when i used the same version in the installation guide , i got everything fine
Thank you

Comment: When added the python path, it got added for python3, but here i want to use python2.7, so can i get help in how to change the path

Comment: First of all, I am very sorry for not answering your question. I am too busy these two days to read it. Based on your comments, I feel that you are not changing the default Python version, you can try the following command:
1.$sudo update-alternatives --list python (This command lists the currently available versions, with 1 as the default)
2.$sudo update-alternatives --config python (This command can be executed according to the version you need, just input the serial number can be implemented)

Comment: According to your last comment, I think it is necessary to update your source file source.list since the $sudo apt-get update error means that you are not connected to the local image and all Ubuntu libraries may fail to link.